# Generate a 1D irregular grid following a particular point density

Tags: matlab

MATLAB has a few functions for building one dimensional grids (`linspace`, logspace, grid, ets). I need a function for generating an irregular one-dimensional grid with certain points distribution density.

Let's say: `nonelinspace(a, b, N, @distr)`, where `a`, `b` is the interval, `N` - the number of points and `distr` is a function of points density (polynomial, Gaussian, hyperbolic, ...).

Is this possible to do in MATLAB?

Additional remarks:
we have an interval [a, b] divided by N = 1000 points: `linspace(a, b, N);` set number of cells (n = 100) and some density distribution function: `distr = @(o) exp(-1e-3*((0:o) - .5*o).^2)` like this.
The expression `N*distr(n)/sum(distr(n))` (or `round(N*distr(n)/sum(distr(n)))`) gives us number of points in every cell. And we need distribute the points EVENTLY along whole interval [a, b].

Comment: does that mean the `a` and `b` are always included values or just limits for that distribution ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how you thought of the sampling of the grid that you want to produce, so I figured a random sampling according to the distribution is what you meant (please correct me if I've misunderstood).

So you actually do have some built in matlab function for that, for example, a uniformly random distribution in the interval `[a b]` of `N` points will be

```
dist = (b-a).*rand(N,1) + a;
```

same tricks can be applied for normal distribution (or gaussian) using `randn`, or Posisson dist using `poissrnd` etc (see more options [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/discrete-distributions.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/continuous-distributions.html)). Other cases can use the unifrom dist rule with a twist of the specific case.